# Transform values in JavaScript array to values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have the following Object.

```
 const result = [{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947}{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947},{date:'2016-10-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947},{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-11-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Bob',score:0.1034947},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Bill',score:0.2081911},{date:'2016-12-21',name:'Mary',score:0.234947}];
```

What I want to take that object and turn those values and put them in separate arrays. So for example,

```
dateArray = ['2016-11-21','2016-10-21', ....]
```

I am really quite new to JavaScript. I am trying to do it with map but not sure if I am on the right track. So thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try writing some code.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yep and I know, I see that you posted that answer I actually wanted to do something more clear since he says he's new to JS than use map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dateArray = [];

for (var index in result) {
    var item = result[index];
    dateArray.push(item.date);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. This nailed it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use **[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)** to transform your array to a new one by projecting every original value with the defined function.

```
var dateArray = result.map(function(r) { 
    return r.date;
});
```

This code literally means "take array `result` and make a new array `dateArray` of the same length where every item is a value of `date` property of corresponding item of `result`".

You can also use arrow-function, but [it is only compatible with ECMAScript 6](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).

```
var dateArray = result.map(r => r.date);
```